# map a stored procedure to a entity in ef5

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I  have a stored procedure which returns the exact columns of an entity I have created in my vs2012 project. The stored procedure is part of my model and is in the folder function imports.
I double clicked the stored procedure and set the returns a collection of - and selected my entity previously mentioned.

In my c# code i use this:

```
 myEntityModel ctx = new myEntityModel();  
 List<myObj> objs = ctx.getMyObjs().ToList();
```

I get this error:

> error 2062: No mapping specified for instances of the EntitySet and
>   AssociationSet in the EntityContainer myEntityModel.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Did you map the properties on your entity to the columns returned by the stored proc?

Right click on the Stored Procedure under Function Imports and select "Function Import Mapping".  A pane should show up for you to map the properties on the entity to the columns returned by the stored proc.

Comment: I have done what you said: the pane shows the stored procedure on left and a left arrow and the fields but I still get the error. When I select the enity I want to map to there is no mapping - I think this is the problem but how do I map the entity to the stored procedure.

Comment: There is mapping for Inset Update Delete but not select.

Comment: But the select is done automatically when you choose the 'return as' in the function imports.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the enitiy to map to my stored procedure so in the end instead of 'returning an entity' in the function imports I returned a complex type and deleted the enity.This allowd me to get the rows into the model.